# Set page origin in QGIS Print Composer OR ArcMap Layout

Tags: arcmap, qgis-3, print-composer, layouts

Working on QGIS 3.6.1 I am reproducing an ArcMap Layout in Print Composer. This is basically pretty straightforward, **but** I need to recalculate the y-position of each map element, because in QGIS Print Composer page origin is top-left corner whereas in ArcMap Layout page origin is bottom-left (thus `y_qgis = page_height - y_arcmap` using the same anchor point).

Since manually doing this calculus for each map element is quite painful, my question: Is there a way to define/set page origin in one of both applications QGIS Print Composer OR ArcMap Layout?

Comment: You can change origin for each element,for example bottom-left

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and ArcMap you wish to ask about in this particular question.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.